# How does Apache handle images/flash when deflate mode is on

Tags: apache, gzip, mod-deflate

I'm thinking of enabling [deflate mode on Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html).  I'm curious how does Apache deal with images or flash files when deflate is on? Does it try to compress images and flash files as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Image file formats supported by the web, as well as videos, PDFs and
>   other binary formats, are already compressed; using gzip on them won't
>   provide any additional benefit, and can actually make them larger. To
>   compress images, see Optimize images."

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/payload#GzipCompression

Answer (score 0):

Sure. If you don't set any filters the server will compress everything if the client supports the compression.

If you use the line from the documentation:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml
```

That would just compress text files with that content types.

Comment: I'm wondering if I should only allow compression for html, css, js files. I'm guessing compressing images and flash files doesn't give me much benefit.

Comment: You can compress any data where you expect that it make sense.